# How can I fix a swift + firebase looping images issue?

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a simple app that lets you upload an image, which has some subposts (like details).
I've correctly made the upload function and process for the main image. But, when finishing up my function for the subposts process, I've encountered an issue (not error), which I know exactly whats causing it and where, but don't know what to do to fix it. (noob here)
I'm using Firebase-Realtime for this app.

In Xcode, I have a button which lets you save all images (including subposts) to the database.

This is ideally what it should look like:

[image: this is ideally what it should look like]

It's very simple.

So, what's the problem?

I have a loop that uploads all subposts to the database, the loop counts each subpost selected, and puts it in an array.

```
var imagePaths = [String]()
var counter = 0
func bulkUpload(_ images: [UIImage], completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    for image in images {
        uploadSubPosts(image) { (urlPath) in
            imagePaths.append(urlPath)
            counter += 1
            if counter == images.count {
                completion(imagePaths)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see, it actually uploads each subpost individually (because of the array), but, the way I'd ideally like it, has it all in a child node.
And, because of it, it uploads many instead of one.
Here is the database right after posting the set of images.

[image: here]

So it's weird but makes sense.
What I'd like is to remove those that don't have the number of subpost images selected. In the pic, I selected 3 images, not 6. And, as you can see there is one of them that is perfect, but 2 that aren't necessary.

So why don't I remove `for image in images`?
Because underneath it (`uploadSubPosts()`) takes an argument.
And can't remove it. Only thing I thought about was adding an array there, but because of the way I made the subposts function, I can only put images in it, hence the `image`

Thanks so much in advance if you decide to help!!
By the way [here is the full subposts function](https://pastebin.com/r6XL1TaC)

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: thanks for the recommendation

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is unclear; the question says *has it all in a child node* and the sub posts *are* in a child node called *subposts*. Also, what you are showing as *ideally* matches, at least in part, what's showing as what you have. can you clarify the question?